# .bash_aliases not parsed right - misquotes and missing first char of each line

Tags: bash, terminal, alias

My .bash_aliases appears to be formatted correctly but when sourced, it is not read correctly. The quotation marks seem to be misplaced and the first character of each line is gone:

```
 ~$ more .bash_aliases
alias e='emacs'
alias gs='git status'
alias ga='git add'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gc='git commit -m'
alias gd='git diff'
alias go='git checkout'
alias jn='jupyter notebook &'
alias od='cd ~/src'
~$ source .bash_aliases
~$ alias
'lias e='emacs
'lias ga='git add
'lias gb='git branch
'lias gc='git commit -m
'lias gd='git diff
'lias go='git checkout
'lias gs='git status
'lias jn='jupyter notebook &
'lias od='cd ~/src
~$ cd src
src$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   cofgox.ipynb

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        #real_users.sql#

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
src$ gs
' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

This has persisted across tmux sessions and regular ssh sessions over many days.
I've looked at questions about .bash_profile and other configuration files and questions about terminal emulators chopping first characters, but have not found anything similar. Very grateful for help - this is just weird.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `hexdump -C .bash_aliases`

Comment: Your file has CRLF line endings. Fix that.

Comment: Ahh. Thank you, @glennjackman (and thanks, @janos)